# Read data in batch

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I want to read data from db using spring jdbctemplate in batches of specific size. I found batchupdate to update table data, but couldn't find any select in batches. Can someone please help me here?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right what you are looking for then

Use [setFetchSize](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#setFetchSize(int)) method to set the fetch size. This would select only specific size.

Answer (score 0):

for writing , we call it batch. For reading, we call it paging. in fact, you can implement by yourself. [Here](https://www.programering.com/a/MTM3EjMwATQ.html) is an example.